# Allocating space for a sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I construct a large, sparse matrix, of which I know the number non-zero elements in advance. Is it possible in R to allocate space for this matrix, instead of having its space automatically increased every time I add an element? Something like [spalloc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/spalloc.html) does in Matlab.

As a simplified code-example of what I want, consider the construction of the following block-wise diagonal matrix.

```
library("Matrix")
n = 1000;
p = 14000;
q = 7;
x_i = Matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p);
x = Matrix(0, n*q, p*q, sparse=TRUE);
for(i in 1:q) {
    x[((i-1)*n+1):(i*n),((i-1)*p+1):(i*p)] = x_i;
}
```

I think this process would be much faster if I could tell R in advance that the matrix will contain n*p*q non-zero elements.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I now see that for the blockwise matrix I should use bdiag()

```
library("Matrix")
n = 1000;
p = 14000;
q = 7;
x_i = Matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p);
lst = list();
for(i in 1:q) {
    lst[i] = x_i;
}
x = bdiag(lst);
```

This is much faster.

Comment: It is often faster to first compute the positions (and values) of all the elements, and only then to construct the sparse matrix, in one go: `sparseMatrix(i=i, j=j, x=x)`.